# Is repeating the MIME type necessary for uploads in Google Drive API?

Tags: android, ios, rest, google-drive-api

I'm trying to decipher the docs for the Google Drive REST API when it comes to uploading a file. For both iOS and Android, the docs seem to require that the MIME type of the upload be specified in two places: in the metadata for the upload and in the media content itself.

For instance, here's how I've been uploading a file in Android:

```
final File fileMetadata = new File()
    .setName("Sample File.mytikkun")
    .setMimeType("application/vnd.zigzagworld.sample")
    .setParents(Collections.singletonList(rootFolderId));

final ByteArrayContent content = ByteArrayContent.fromString(
    "application/vnd.zigzagworld.sample",
    "Sample data");

mDriveService
    .files()
    .create(fileMetadata, content)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
```

And here's the same thing in iOS/Swift:

```
let metaData = GTLRDrive_File()
metaData.name = "Sample File.mytikkun"
metaData.mimeType = "application/vnd.zigzagworld.sample"
metaData.parents = [ prefs.rootFolderId! ]

let content = GTLRUploadParameters(
    data: "Sample Data".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
    mimeType: "application/vnd.zigzagworld.sample")

let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(
    withObject: metaData,
    uploadParameters: content)
query.fields = "id"

service.executeQuery(query) { ticket, file, error in
    // ...
}
```

The above codes work, but the repetition of the MIME type seems like a code smell. Is there some way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two mime types serve different purposes. Drive is capable of converting (say) an MS Excel sheet to a Google Spreadsheet during upload. So the mime type within the File metadata is saying which mime type the resulting Drive file should be. The mime type in the upload request is how Drive should interpret the existing file format.

Comment: That makes sense. If I leave out the MIME type from the metadata, will Drive pick up the MIME type from the content? (I suppose I could try it to find out, but this approach just now occurred to me and asking seems easier than experimenting. )

Comment: it might do, but since it's an undocumented behaviour, it could change. Furthermore you run the risk of a library "helping" you by providing a value. So imho it's way safer to be explicit in specifying the target mime type.